# new /review reviewed count bug

Tags: bug, review

The sum of all of the posts that were reviewed by everyone today do not add to the total that was posted.

[image]

Does this mean that something was deleted? I find that rather hard to believe as  think many more than one post was deleted.
If that was not why the count went down, what is going on?

Comment: Obviously its wrong if I'm not above you!

Comment: @IvoFlipse, I'm just trying to make it possible for you to mash delete :)

Comment: I see 10 users in the "Top Reviewers today". Maybe it is actually the "**Top 10** Reviewers today" list? This would explain why the numbers don't add up.

Comment: I don't know. I also know that I have gone backwards a few times in the overall count

Comment: @iglvzx, the list can hold more than 10 users (see it now for an example)

Comment: @soandos Ok. You are correct. Good catch.

Comment: While this is on-topic for Meta.SU, I suggest that you make these requests/bug reports onto Meta.SO as these are more of a general system reporting and not particularly related solely to Super User.  This actually has [it's own post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) where people are already reporting bugs and requesting features.