# Review count goes down sometimes

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Here is an example (Tom's count went down).

Beginning:
[image]

End:
[image]

It almost seems like I "stole" reviews from Tom, but that would be strange.

Comment: why post this again? [new /review reviewed count bug](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5193)

Comment: Different bug. Here, the count went backwards. There, the count did not add correctly

Comment: I gotta ask.  Is this really that big of a deal?

Comment: @KronoS, nope, but it is a bug, and I have no idea how much havoc that can cause under other circumstances.

Comment: While this is on-topic for Meta.SU, I suggest that you make these requests/bug reports onto Meta.SO as these are more of a general system reporting and not particularly related solely to Super User.  This actually has [it's own post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) where people are already reporting bugs and requesting features.

Comment: This is the crap queue. Chances are, deleted posts don't count towards the total (which is a bad idea, but conceivable).

Comment: @KronoS, those are suggestions. This is a bug (though by all means, if a mod wants to migrate it, please do so)

Comment: @soandos I talked to Rebecca Chernoff and she said that bugs are being reported there as well.

Comment: Flagging for migration then. Thanks for the update.

Comment: While all the comments above may be true, MSU is as valid a Meta as MSO. I'm sure soandos got the message that he should post /review specific feedback on the said post, but other than that MSU is just that: Meta. There's no real difference

Comment: @ivoflipse I completely agree that these are valid and on topic here I was more trying to keep these in one place. Also MSO gets more traffic for these sort of things.

Answer (score 2):

Before we implemented client-side review throttling, it was more common for reviews to be invalidated server-side several minutes after they were submitted. You shouldn't observe this behavior any more.