# Reviewing the same item two (or more times) times

Tags: bug, review

Here is a screenshot of me reviewing a post that I reviewed earlier:

[image]

I know that it has happened many more times, but this is the first that I had had a comment on the post that would tell me for sure that that I review it previously. It also happens a few times in a row:
[image]

Comment: You should really be posting these bug reports on Meta.SO.

Comment: @iglvzx See last comment to http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5200/review-count-goes-down-sometimes As an aside, I don't like MSO (just does not *feel* as nice as here)

Comment: @soandos if you're going to be a mod you better get used to MSO.

Comment: @KronoS Perhaps what I said above was slightly too strong. Given a choice, I much prefer here to MSO. Also as an aside, there looks to be no danger I will be a mod anytime soon.